# Go lang fyne change container content with button

Tags: go, containers, lang, fyne

I'm very new to coding so this is difficult for me to figure out how to do, I've tried looking docs n google but without help!

I got 3 buttons where I want one of them to change the new,vmax container with a new container having data specified in the button func, but I can't seem to figure out how I on the button can change the container content or the whole container

This is my code for now

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var Menu = []string{"Home", "App-Status"}

func main() {
    var W fyne.Window
    a := app.New()
    a.Settings().SetTheme(theme.DarkTheme())
    W = a.NewWindow("Application-OutSight")
    W.Resize(fyne.NewSize(640, 460))
    text := widget.NewLabel("Welcome to This App")

    // start container with welcome text
    contentcontainer := container.NewMax(text)

    split := (container.NewHSplit(
        menuBar(Menu),
        contentcontainer,
    ))
    split.Offset = 0.2
    W.SetContent(split)
    W.ShowAndRun()
}

func menuBar(Menu []string) *widget.List {
    listView := widget.NewList(func() int {
        return len(Menu)
    },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return widget.NewLabel("template")
        },
        func(id widget.ListItemID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
            o.(*widget.Label).SetText(Menu[id])
        })
    listView.OnSelected = func(id widget.ListItemID) {
        if id == 0 {
            //when i click here i want to change the start container to this container but not the sidebare as shown on picture only the container with the welcome text
            somevaluefunction()
            anothervaluefunction()
            contentcontainer = container.NewMax(somevaluefunction(), anothervaluefunction())
            // return or refresh the container in main with this new one

        } else if id == 1 {
            fmt.Println("app")
        }
        if id == 2 {
            fmt.Println("exit")
        }
    }
    return listView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `split.Objects[1]` or put a named container inside there and set it’s content directly (avoiding the `[1]` to access second item of a split.

Comment: hmm i dont see how that helps me ill re change my post to make it more clear what im trying to archive :D

Comment: If you want to replace the whole window content then just call `Window.SetContent` again